# How to share pictures from Photos to Instagram

Tags: google-photos

I am on an older Android phone (Motorols Droid Turbo 2), and want to share an album (or even just single photos) from Google Photos to Instagram. I went through the steps of sharing on Photos, but Instagram is not an option to share to. Please let me know if there is a way to add Instagram as a sharing option to Google Photos on Android. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is it just Instagram that's now showing up, or is it that you don't see any apps to share with?

Comment: Why can't you download the photos from Google photos and then share them from gallery or file manager to Instagram? Of you're sure Instagram doesn't pop

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find the photo when you are uploading from within the Instagram app, it's because the photo isn't saved to your device.

1. Open Google Photos
2. Navigate to the photo you want and click on it.
3. At the top right, there are 3 dots that you must click, then click "save to device
4. Open the Instagram app, start the upload process.

The only problem I could imagine you running into is that it won't be the first photo available. Depending on when the photo was taken you might have to scroll down to find it.